# Use a Joptionpane string input inside a if statement

Tags: java, string, swing, if-statement, joptionpane

I'm starting to learn java and I have a trouble with one of my programme. 
I'm trying to obtain the inductance of an antenna depending on the type of antenna enter by the user. 
The problem is that I have the dialog box and I enter the input, but after that my code stop and it didn't do the loop. I have been looking over the web and I can't find why my input is not acceptable by the if statement. 
This is part of my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
//import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Antenna_Inductance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // first we will define all the variable use of the problem set

        // for the lime antenna
       double M;
       int N1;
       int N2;
       double R1;
       double R2;
      // now we can start to programmed the main code 

       String Type= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type of Antenna");
        // this is where the code stop and i don't know why

    if (Type == "line") {
           String input_rmin= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter minimum distance for r");
            double rmin = Double.parseDouble(input_rmin);
            String input_rmax= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter maximum distance for r");
            double rmax = Double.parseDouble(input_rmax);
           I = 0.01;
           for (r=rmin; r==rmax ;r+=0.05) {

           B_line = (mu*I)/(2*pi*r);

        System.out.println("Inductance for line antenna =" + B_line);
           }
```

So, i could really use some help on this one. Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: JOptionPane is for usage in a JFrame window. String comparison: `if (Type.equals("line")) {`. Check demos out.

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question right, this should be what you are looking for:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    //import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Antenna_Inductance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // first we will define all the variable use of the problem set

        // for the lime antenna
        double M;
        int N1;
        int N2;
        double R1;
        double R2;
        // now we can start to programmed the main code

        String type = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(new JFrame(),
                "Enter Antenna or what ever:", "titleForJInputDialog" , JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
        // this is where the code stop and i don't know why
        System.out.println("Input of JOptionPane: " + type);
        if (type.equals("line")) {
            System.out.println("Input of JOptionPane is the same like 'line'");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. that help a lot